# Set the mean/average of a column on a variable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame and I like to get the average of a column. If I get it like this:

```
avg_NoPItems = df.groupBy().mean('NoPItems').collect()
```

Later I can't use to compare with any values because I get a data frame object. So, How can I get the mean as number not as dataframe?

PD: I have tried this but don't work:

```
avg_NoPItems = df.groupBy().mean('NoPItems').collect()[0]
```

Comment: why you use a group by, i think you can simply select(mean( "NoPItems")  :   df.select(mean("NoPItems").as("mean")).first.getAs[Double]("mean")

Comment: I can't use that, pyspark said invalid sintaxis with the `....as("mean"))...`

Comment: sorry i'am using scala, for python i think is ( but not sure) : `df.select(mean("NoPItems").alias("mean")).first["‌​mean"]`

Comment: Neither works `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I have found a temporary solution: `df.groupBy().mean('NoPItems').collect()[0][0]`

Comment: the method  .first return a Row, you can check the spark python doc 
 http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. df.groupBy().mean('NoPItems').collect() will return the list of Row Objects.
2. df.groupBy().mean('NoPItems').collect()[0] will return the first Row object.
3. df.groupBy().mean('NoPItems').collect()[0][0] will return the first value within the first Row. Change the index in order to fetch the desired value.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks